# Fetch data from youtube video list

Tags: php, youtube-api

I want to display the latest 5 videos of a youtube channel including title, views, thumbnail, etc. for a analysis.

But how can i display the next video after i displayed the first. because there is no id=1 for latest e.g.

So i want to dipslay the first video with details and then the secound one,etc.

I use PHP and HTML

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
 "etag": "\"nlUZBA6NbTS7q9G8D1GljyfTIWI/sqVszgEMcgndBQQW-8aekztyFWo\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
 "regionCode": "DE",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 313,
  "resultsPerPage": 5
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"nlUZBA6NbTS7q9G8D1GljyfTIWI/C8zU9hXFXvoOaiyzihj3QdaM3nk\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "eWTpXZ-sspk"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-08-28T16:30:11.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCzfu8Y5CsN7OCLJhZy_fH6w",
    "title": "RBX.Tools - Earn FREE Robux! (3,000 Giveaway)",
    "description": "Want to earn free robux? Our website allows you to do that easily without any limits! Check it out: https://rbx.tools Robux giveaway: ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eWTpXZ-sspk/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eWTpXZ-sspk/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/eWTpXZ-sspk/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "MRMURK4G3",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"nlUZBA6NbTS7q9G8D1GljyfTIWI/f-4ch1LXyzfYIL4utWuPz6CRFck\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "IVby2exqn1w"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-02-09T23:38:15.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCzfu8Y5CsN7OCLJhZy_fH6w",
    "title": "How To: Setup/Use Discord Webhooks! (PHP)",
    "description": "In this video i show you how to use discord webhooks for any custom event you would like using a simple cURL request in PHP. Find this video helpful in any ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IVby2exqn1w/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IVby2exqn1w/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/IVby2exqn1w/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "MRMURK4G3",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"nlUZBA6NbTS7q9G8D1GljyfTIWI/xq6mXfyCDDr8-C03ueN-4GhGP7U\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "QcD6RLYc34w"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-12-01T21:26:39.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCzfu8Y5CsN7OCLJhZy_fH6w",
    "title": "How To: Make A Qooh.Me Spammer! (C#)",
    "description": "In this video i show you how to make a simple spammer for anonymous question websites. Find this video helpful in any way? Be sure to drop a like & comment ...",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QcD6RLYc34w/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QcD6RLYc34w/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/QcD6RLYc34w/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "MRMURK4G3",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
   "etag": "\"nlUZBA6NbTS7q9G8D1GljyfTIWI/J8WfMLAVh58rILoataElddP5Q_o\"",
   "id": {
    "kind": "youtube#video",
    "videoId": "iAwevpZK9Ug"
   },
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2017-11-19T19:21:23.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCzfu8Y5CsN7OCLJhZy_fH6w",
    "title": "Proxies24",
    "description": "Advertisement video, please click off if you're not interested! This is a short video to get a new site im a part of get started. Please let me know your thoughts on it.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iAwevpZK9Ug/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iAwevpZK9Ug/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/iAwevpZK9Ug/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "MRMURK4G3",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**YouTube Data API** request returns the JSON data that includes the information of the video (title, description, thumbnails, publish date, etc.). You need to specify the API key ($API_key), YouTube Channel ID ($channelID).

```
//Get videos from channel by YouTube Data API
$API_key    = 'Insert_Your_API_Key';
$channelID  = 'Insert_Channel_ID';
$maxResults = 10;

$videoList = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order=date&part=snippet&channelId='.$channelID.'&maxResults='.$maxResults.'&key='.$API_key.''));
```

**Youtube Video List using PHP**
Loop through the $videoList->items to list the videos from a YouTube channel.

```
foreach($videoList->items as $item){
    //Embed video
    if(isset($item->id->videoId)){
        echo '<div class="youtube-video">
                <iframe width="280" height="150" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'.$item->id->videoId.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <h2>'. $item->snippet->title .'</h2>
            </div>';
    }
}
```

*In the YouTube video list, Video ID and Title are used, but you can show the other information as per your requirement. The following information is provided by the API.*

- YouTube Video ID – $item->id->videoId
- YouTube Video Publish Date – $item->snippet->publishedAt
- YouTube Channel ID – $item->snippet->channelId
- YouTube Video Title – $item->snippet->title
- YouTube Video Description – $item->snippet->description
- YouTube Video Thumbnail URL (default size) – $item->snippet->thumbnails->default->url
- YouTube Video Thumbnail URL (medium size) – $item->snippet->thumbnails->medium->url
- YouTube Video Thumbnail URL (large size) – $item->snippet->thumbnails->high->url
- YouTube Channel Title – $item->snippet->channelTitle

Comment: If i want to embed to my HTML page i just get:

items as $item){ //Embed video if(isset($item->id->videoId)){ echo '

'. $item->snippet->title .'
'; } } ?>